# Portable executable stack size and operation (x64)

Tags: 64-bit, portable-executable

In this image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

Under the code section it lists the first instruction as subtracting 0x28 from the stack pointer.  Why would it need to subtract from a stack pointer that should be 0, right?  Or does it start at the top and work down?  Where in the PE headers do you specify the stack size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack pointer doesn't have to be 0. In fact, and as Windows uses a flat memory model, it will have some non-zero value, big enough to allow growing downwards as stack is needed.

The action of substracting a value to the stack pointer is commonly found in the standard prologue of C functions. It allows a function to reserve stack space for local variables. Sometimes the compiler adds its own local variables to aid in some optimizations, or to help some stack checking functions linked to the program if you chose to check for stack buffer overflows at runtime.

You can see the commited and reserved stack space in a PE executable by using the DUMPBIN utility on that executable with the /HEADERS option. You can change both the reserved and commited stack size using Linker options (in Visual Studio)